Evaluating the PDF of an active Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process
I am going through this paper: Inertial Self-Propelled Particles.
For a free-particle, when there is no external potential, the authors have written the stochastic differential equations as -
$$\dot{\vec{x}}=\vec{v},$$
$$\dot{\vec{v}}=-\gamma\vec{v}+\frac{\vec{f^a}}{m}+\sqrt{2\gamma\frac{T}{m}}\vec{\eta},$$
$$\tau\dot{\vec{f^a}}=-\vec{f^a}+f_0\sqrt{2\tau}\vec{\xi}.$$
Where $\vec{f^a}$ is the self-propulsion, $\vec{\eta}$ and $\vec{\xi}$ are Gaussian white noise, and other symbols have their usual meaning.
In the paper, they have generalized the above three equations as the following multi-componenet equation:
$$\dot{\textbf{w}}=-\mathcal{A}\cdot\textbf{w}+\sqrt{2}\sigma\cdot\textbf{$\eta$}.$$
A being the 'drift matrix' and $\sigma$ the 'noise matrix'. Here, $\textbf{w}\equiv(\vec{x},\vec{v},\vec{f^a})$.
When the correlation matrix $\mathcal{C}$ satisfies: $$\mathcal{A}.\mathcal{C}+\mathcal{C}.\mathcal{A}^T=2\mathcal{D},$$
with $\mathcal{D}=\sigma.\sigma^T$. Then, steady-state probability density, $$p(\textbf{w})\propto \text{exp}\left( -\textbf{w}.\mathcal{C}^{-1}.\textbf{w} \right).$$
I have been through several chapters of Nonequilibrium statistical mechanics by V. Balakrishnan, and also browsed through some other books like Gardiner and Risken, but still cannot figure out exactly how to arrive at the final PDF.
It would be very helpful if someone can outline the methodology, for any general multivariable stochastic process.

I think there is no stationary distribution for the free-particle case. Otherwise, mean square displacement would not depend on time (see formula (15) of the paper). So you probably won't be able to deduce the last expression from the first three.

The equation of motion are linear and the noise is gaussian, thus the variables must follow a gaussian distribution (take for example the fourier transform of the equation to see this!). A (mumtivariate) gaussian distribution is fully determined by the averages (0 in this case) and the variance/correlation between variables (C). From these follow the last distribution you gave.
